# 25% bounce rate on single-page application

Tags: google-analytics

I have a single-page website (just launched on a small-scale) and I was thinking the bounce rate would be 100% since there's no other page on the site to visit. Instead I'm seeing bounce rate of 25% on Google Analytics.[image]

How is the bounce rate calculated?

Comment: Formulaically, the bounce rate is calculated as the total number of visitors viewing only one page on your site divided by the total number of visitors to the web page. Do you have events that fire on your site automatically? This may bring down your bounce rate.

Comment: Also check that you don't have the tracking code twice on your page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bounce rate can be a bit confusing if you don't understand exactly what it is. Here's how the Google Analytics Help Center defines it:

> Bounce Rate is the percentage of single-page sessions (i.e. sessions
>   in which the person left your site from the entrance page without
>   interacting with the page).

In other words, if you send **any** other data to GA during that sessions, it's not a bounce. (The one exception to this is when you send a hit as [non-interactive](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#implementation) via the [`nonInteraction`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#nonInteraction) parameter).

From you screenshot above, it says you have 5.58 pages per session, which means you must be sending some additional pageview hits, so that explains why your bounce rate isn't 100%.